# Which notation should be used for the mean, SD, and median: mean±SD or mean (SD)?

Tags: mean, median, notation

I usually use **mean±SD** notation for reporting values. I know that many people use **mean (SD)** notation and I understand why.

Right now in the document I am writing I am also reporting medians but I don't know which notation I should use for the 3 measures. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Both conventions you mention are ambiguous - for example you can't tell whether the number after the $\pm$ is a standard deviation, a standard error, or the half-width of an interval. (a problem that has led to numerous questions on this site).

If you're publishing somewhere that offers precise guidelines follow those, but otherwise I suggest being explicit, for example: $``\text{median } 28.5,$ $\text{ mean } 31.2,$ $\text{ standard deviation } 3.6\!"$ -- then there's no possibility of misinterpretation.

Comment: +1. I usually write $``31.2 \pm 3.6\text{ (mean}\pm\text{SD)}\!"$ and hope that this is clear enough...

Comment: @amoeba That's explicit, so it looks okay to me. I wasn't trying to hold people to any one format, just avoiding ambiguity; yours does that.

Comment: Well, I end up using 5.0 (5) ± 0.5 (2.5) [0 - 10] for the hypothesis variable (the numbers I show here are not the true values) and inserted a footnote explaining the format Mean (Median) ± SD (Q1-Q3) [Min - Max]. For all other variables, since they are presented in tables, it was inserted a table footnote explaining the format: Mean ± SD [Min - Max] or Median (Q1-Q3)

Answer (score 1):

I personally usually use *Mean (Median) $\pm$ SD (IQR) [Min - Max]*. That's quite maximalist, so may be a bit too much for certain purposes/readers, but is a quite logical grouping of indicators (central tendency $\pm$ dispersion, with traditional indicator first, robust alternative in parenthesis), I believe. (Minimum and maximum is of course added not because they're statistically especially important or good indicators, but because on the biomedical field it is often required for ''clinical'' purposes.)

Comment: I actually like this idea, but only if the order is explicitly specified in the paper so the reader knows what they're looking at

Comment: @ssdecontrol: Of course! I usually specify it in the - say - table caption.